# pydev support for nose2

Tags: pydev, nose

I've been running nose tests successfully with PyDev and wanted to give nose2 a try.

So I installed it with

```
pip install nose2
```

copy/pasted the sample code from http://nose2.info/ into a new module called 'test_script_with_nose2':

```
from nose2.compat import unittest
from nose2.tools import params

def tests_can_be_functions():
    assert True

def tests_can_be_generators():
    def check(val):
        assert val == val, "Identity failure!"
    for i in range(1, 4):
        yield check, i

@params(1, 2, 3)
def tests_can_take_parameters(p):
    assert p < 4, "How'd that get here?"

class TestsCanBeUnittestTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.x = 1
    def test_one(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.x, 1)

class TestsCanBePlainClasses(object):
    def setUp(self):
        self.me_too = 1
    def test(self):
        assert self.me_too == 1, "Not me too?"
```

But I get this error

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_script_with_nose2.tests_can_take_parameters
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
TypeError: tests_can_take_parameters() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.014s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I have nose selected as the unit test runner in pydev, but perhaps it needs a new runner for nose2? if so, anyone knows how to do this? Or am I missing something trivial here?

Answer (score 0):

This unresolved answer is a couple of years delayed, but I wanted to provide this information.

This line in the error you provided indicates that nose is being used instead of nose2, since nose2 is a separate package installable via pip:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
```

I also attempted to use `nose2` in pydev, upgrading from `nose`. I uninstalled `nose` and installed `nose2` and then tried to run the test code you provided, but it failed on import of `nose2` instead of the error you provided.

```
ImportError: No module named nose2.compat
```

Then, I tried some unit tests I already had, but got the following message:

```
Warning: Could not import the test runner: --nose-params. Running with the default pydev unittest runner instead.
```

So it seems nose2 is still unsupported in pydev as of this date.